# How to start progress dialog on button click of alert dialog in android?

Tags: android, progressdialog, android-alertdialog

I want to start progress dialog on click of YES button of Alert Dialog. But when I run it. It gives me a warning of Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of. It sometimes works and sometimes gives warning.
And the progress dialog does not starts. Please provide some suggestions

Comment: Try like [this](http://pastie.org/4625670)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example -

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    AlertDialog.Builder ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    ab.setMessage("Choose Yes/No :");
    ab.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            arg0.dismiss();
            ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(PDActivity.this);
            pd.setMessage("test");
            pd.show();
            pd.setCancelable(true);
        }
    });

    ab.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    ab.show();
}
```

Try like above..

Answer (score 2):

Dismiss alert dialog prior to starting progress dialog.

Answer (score 2):

when click on yes button,first dismiss alert dialog then start progress dialog.